# I want to get exact coordinates from agm-map when I click on any place or when info window open

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular6, angular-google-maps

[This is image please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZPy8.png)

```html
<agm-map (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker (markerClick)="mapClicked(place)" *ngFor="let place of searchplace" [iconUrl]="place.icon" [latitude]="place.geometry.location ? place.geometry.location.lat() : ''"
          [longitude]="place.geometry.location ? place.geometry.location.lng() : ''">        
        </agm-marker>       
      </agm-map>
```

I am using agm-map, I want to get coords/placeId when click on any place.
I just want to get this place cords for get place details.I used mapClick function but it's not giving me particular place cords.Please help me to get cords/placeId whenever I click on any place and infowindow open for.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to get the *placeId* is to listen for the [mapReady](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#mapReady) event. When it fires, you'll get an instance of the map, which you can then add a click listener to. When the user clicks a place on the map, if it's a place on Google Maps (AKA: a "*POI*" or (Point Of Interest)), then you'll get back an object that includes the place's *placeId*.

**map.component.html:**

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" ... ></agm-map>
```

**map.component.ts:**

```
public onMapReady(map) {
  map.addListener('click', (e) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

In the code above, 'e' will be your object that includes a *placeId* (if the user clicked on a place). If the user didn't click a place, no *placeId* will be returned.

Note: I think they're working on a (AGM-specific) way to return the *placeId* through the `mapClick` event, but for the time being - before that gets implemented and released, this should work.